# Printer driver generate UFM or GTT file

Tags: windows, printing, fonts, driver

Can anyone shed some light on how one would generate a UFM or GTT file? Do I convert an existing font file, perhaps a TTF to this format? I've read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547259(v=vs.85).aspx) and understand that they are just binary files containing structs. I don't really think I should be handcrafting these though... so is there a tool?

I've built the text-only driver sample (WinDDK) which comes with some GTT and UFM files but obviously I need to define my own font metrics. Some of my fonts are of a different cpi that the UFMs provided so I don't really know how to proceed.

**Edit:**

My problem and not the attempted solution: I am trying to build a unidrv minidriver printer driver and I'll need to support custom fonts. If GTT/UFM is not the best route please let me know. I'd love to avoid the v3 model entirely but I have requirement to support XP SP3 through Windows 8.1. Windows 10 will be another story.

Comment: perhaps a silly question, but: why? what are you trying to achieve that you decided you needed to use UFM/GTT for? Because avoiding [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is a good idea.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for pointing out that I was doing that in my question.

Comment: hm, reading up on [unidrv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidrv) on good ol' wikipedia suggests it can work directly with OpenType fonts, in which case no conversion should be needed. Did you run into any concrete issues that suggest it can't deal with your ttf (or otf - both are opentype fonts, just different outline subtabling) files?

Comment: I've seen reference to that but the Microsoft documentation on the topic is rather opaque. If more concise docs exist, they are well hidden. Do you have experience building Windows drivers by any chance?

Comment: last windows I programmed for was win95, but following the chain starting at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and ending at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it sounds like you can just use the default table and see if Arial now "magically" works? (using substitution rather than pretending you have a hardware font)